# What should we feel when reading a novel any genre romantic or any other

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sharia

Assalam alaikum I want to know what should a person feel when reading a fiction novel like when we read romantic genre or any other genre we feel happy when main character win a fight or when non mehrams are dating as in many novel or interacting with each other and joking with each other we feel happy and amused or sad when they left each other and all the other emotion a person  feel when reading is it kufr to have such feeling when reading since being pleased with kufr is also kufr? Also I know that what is happening in the novel Is not real since it is fiction not do I have intention to do a sin in that case will it be alright to read it?
'

Comment: When you read a book or watch a movie/TV show about a serial killer, does that mean you're committing kufr because you have a feeling of excitement of what's going to happen next despite murder being haram in Islam? What about Breaking Bad when they sell meth and fight each other, even though intoxicants are haram?

It is fiction, as long as you're not in such a vulnerable state where such a piece of fiction can lead you to haram temptations or sin then there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you I really needed that answer